# AWS Microservices and API Throttling on client side.

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, web-services, throttling

A microservice is hosted on AWS ECS. MS calls various outside apis to get data. We want to throttle the calls to the outside world. I know API gateways should have this on their side but here we want to control the throttle limit, we dont care what api provider do. Problem is with single microservice we can alaways have circular queues etc to throttle the limit but in case of AWS and auto scaling, we don't know how many instances would spon up and how to adjust the limits on the fly.

So, we need a cental solution to control the flow. Any suggestions / frameworks that you know of does this thing ?

Comment: what's wrong with api gateway why can't you use that ?

Comment: That is not under our control. Assume you are hitting twitter api (for ex) and they have a policy that if you exceed 10 concurrent request then from 11th the charges would be 4 times to hit their api, so as a developer you should make sure on your side that you don't exceed 10 concurrent requests. Similar is the situation.

Comment: what about a reverse proxy are you flexible with that ?

Comment: hey there is a new feature introduced in reinvent 2018 where you can route traffic from elastic load balancer to lambda function can it be useful in your case ?